# problem with NTFS partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs

I have Windows and Ubuntu both installed in my laptop. Recently, during Windows installation when the computer took an update, the whole computer broke down. I had to fix the boot loader with Boot-Repair from a live Ubuntu USB. I have Ubuntu back, but after repair it is no longer possible to login into Windows. I checked my HDD with `GParted`, and it was showing errors in the Windows partition and also other NTFS partition. I am trying to fix the partition with the following commands but still having this error.

```
rashed@rashed:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking file system overflow... FAILED
Error: Failed to fix the alternate boot sector
```

Is there a way to fixed the problem?

Comment: Boot-Repair fixes Grub but can't fix NTFS partitions errors. As a matter of fact, nothing in Ubuntu can. You need to use Windows to fix NTFS partitions. You can boot Windows installation media for that. Specific instructions are obviously off-topic here. Once done you may need to run Boot-Repair again.

Comment: Does the NTFS partition mount?

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto yes it does

Comment: Good. If it mounts you can access all the files you need and copy them to another drive.

Answer (score 2):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

## in Windows...

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: The other day my entire windows os broke down. and after that I have the errors in ubuntu

Comment: **Did you follow my instructions?** Give more details about Windows OS problems, and errors in Ubuntu. That's the only way anybody can help. Put that information into your original question, and ping me `@heynnema` and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you please take a look. @heynnema

Comment: @rashedazad If you're not able to boot into Windows, you'll probably need a Windows install/repair disc to fix the problem... or connect the disk to another Windows computer to fix the problem using chkdsk.

Comment: @heynnema Hi!  If you are going to post the same answer across multiple questions, first check if the question here and the question you originally answered are similar enough to be duplicates.  If they are, consider flagging or close voting the question as a duplicate instead of copying your answer across multiple questions.